# Using java beans / command / java class with getter setter almost same every where is good practice

Tags: java, class, design-patterns, memory, javabeans

We are using Spring, Hibernate and DWR in our web application and I have question regarding using of beans / command in application.

Currently we are reusing most of beans where ever its possible. So at some places we need only 3-4 fields and that are available in one bean but that bean also have other many fields (in many cases this other fields are more that 20-25).

**Example:**

we have one bean / command called `OrderCommand` which has following fields:

```
id, name, total, price, tax, fee, displayId, orderCreated, createdBy, cancelledDate, cancelledBy, listItems (List<ItemCommand), listDiscountCommand (List<DiscountCommand>).
```

Now if at one place we need only `id`, `name`, `total` then also we use `OrderCommand` and at another place we required `displayId`, `price`, `tax`, `fee`, `total`, `orderCreated`, `createdBy` then also we use `OrderCommand`.

SO MY QUESTION IS THAT IS THIS OKAY THAT WE USE SAME COMMAND AT MANY PLACES THOUGH MANY OF ITS FIELDS ARE UNUSED.

So is this creates any problem or its perfectly okay.

Thanks.

Comment: What does "almost same" mean. Are you asking if you should follow bean conventions everywhere?

Comment: Have you tried it to see?

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? Is it about reusing ? Please give more info or some examples to understand

Comment: Do the other fields have default value?

Comment: @chiefTow.. : almost same means if its related to order then OrderCommand is used. then wheter that usage req. 1-2 fields or all we use OrderCommand.

Comment: @ScaryWombat yes this way we are using from very long. but now we are doing memory profiling and improvement related things and so considering every tiny points of improvement.

Comment: @MertMertce no we are not setting any value to other fields

Comment: Generally when there are so lots of fields, the idea would be create a structure, a class, or override the constructor, or design various hierarchical beans. Passing lots of fields separately (and much of them unnecessary) would not improve things.

Comment: Why not just handle it when it's requested in the controller? Make a "trimmed" object called "`OrderSummary`" and another complex dt named "`OrderDetail`" each with the appropriate fields?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils this is just two example but we are using the same command for almost more than 50 different places. and we are also having many different commands. So around we have 40-50 commands which we are using at some more than 500 places.

Answer (score 2):

From a purist approach, it's almost never nice to reuse the dto you use for your view in your domain. And from a sane person's perspective, you NEVER use the same object for different purpose.

I'd never reuse any view object in my domain and vice versa. Even more, I'd never reuse a command object on two different places (unless it is really the same command, but then why are you invoking it from two different places?) because if you do that, you'd tightly couple everything and then you will for sure pay for that should the two things need separation.

Using a different object for each of your concerns allows you to really separate concerns between your different MVC layers and between each component within the layers, and you won't have code creep and it will make your refactoring and testing procedure faster and better.

http://codebetter.com/jpboodhoo/2007/09/27/screen-bound-dto-s/

Should you still want to reuse something, you should come up with a hierarchy that you are sure is going to be shared between all your entities (orders) in this case.

Something like:

```
public class Order {
  private Integer id;
}

public class SomeOrder extends Order {
  private String orderName;
}

public class SomeOtherOrder extends Order {

  private Long orderQuantity;
}
```

**EDIT:** Due to the comments, I will clarify a bit. If you have different types of orders, it makes sense you indeed have a hierarchical class structure in which each of your orers inherits or extends a base OrderCommand class as shown in the examples above. In what you've said:

> Now if at one place we need only id, name, total then also we use
>   OrderCommand and at another place we required displayId, price, tax,
>   fee, total, orderCreated, createdBy then also we use OrderCommand.

If you **already know that in one place you need** only id, name, total and in another name you need fee, total, displayId, etc.., then **this is logic in your application** and should be represented as such, so you **should create the appropriate OOP classes to reflect it**. Otherwise you can just be passing an Object everywhere, right?

About ending up with hundreds of classes. I think you are exaggerating there but if you have hundred of types of orders that each have different meaning (and properties), then you should have hundreds of classes in the first place. Classes are used to convey meaning and are the building blocks of logic and that is what they should be used for in an OOP aspect.

Comment: So is the purist approach then to provide a specific dto for each view even if they're the same?

Comment: But if we go with your purist approach then we will be having hundreds of command and that makes managing things more complex.